# http referer только для формы

Tags: javascript, html5, django

По некоторым причинам пришлось сделать

```
<head>
   <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
</head>
```

Однако на этой же странице, в форме отправки post запроса по причине наличия и нежелания отключать CSRF всё же **referer** проверяется, и нужен. 
Форма вида:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{ path }}">
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="f">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Подскажите, можно ли его обратно включить для формы?

Варианты с отключением его проверки (*без отключения токена*) так же рассматриваю.

Comment: Так может проще использоыать same-origin вместо no-referer?

Comment: @alexey-ten да, помогло. Добавил в форму <meta name="referrer" content="same-origin" /> и заработало как надо.

Comment: Если напишите как ответ - плюсану и отмечу как решение :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо политики `no-referer` можно использовать `same-origin`. В таком случае `Referer` будет отсылаться только при переходах (запросах) на тот же домен. А при переходах на другие домены заголовка `Referer` не будет.

Документация [MDN Referrer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).